# "This" in anonymous inner object

Tags: java, groovy, closures, inner-classes, anonymous-class

I want to write a groovy version of this java code:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static main(args) {
        def server = Server.builder()
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                      public void handle(final Ev ev){
                          ev.dispatch(this)
                      }
                    }
                }).build()
        server.start()
    }
}
```

My resulting groovy code is:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static main(args) {
        def server = Server.builder()
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                      public void handle(final Ev ev){
                          ev.dispatch(this)
                      }
                    }
                }).build()
        server.start()
    }
}
```

The problem comes from the ev.dispatch(this): ev.dispatch require an HttpHandler object but "this" in groovy, even typecasting it, don't produce an HttpHandler object.

I have tried replace "this" with "delegate" or "owner" but nothing changed.

I have tried to replace the anonim inner class with a closure but with no different esit:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static main(args) {
        def server = Server.builder()
                .setHandler({ ev -> 
                      public void handle(final Ev ev){
                          ev.dispatch(this)
                      }
                    } as HttpHandler
                ).build()
        server.start()
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?? (using groovy 2.3.6)

Comment: "...but in groovy version this refer to the HelloWorld outer object." - That is almost not possible.  There is no instance of HelloWorld being created in your example.  Are you sure that is what `this` is referring to?

Comment: Is it referring to an object that is an instance of HelloWorld, or is it evaluating to the HelloWorld class (like HelloWord.class would)?

Comment: I have run the first Groovy example posted in the description (after fixing the mismatched curly brace) and `this` does not refer to an instance of `HelloWorld`, `this` refers to an instance of `HelloWorld$1`, which is the anonymous inner class which is an instance of `HttpHandler`, which is what `this` is supposed to refer to there.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown you are right println "this" echoes HelloWorld$1. But if I try to cast it to HttpHandler i got this Exception: Cannot cast object 'class mypkg.Underdog$1' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'mypkg.HttpHandler'

Comment: You really should change the wording of "but in groovy version this refer to the HelloWorld outer object" because you have people spending (wasting) their time investigating something that isn't happening. I would edit it myself but I think the policy is that edits of other people's questions are not supposed to change the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the following:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static main(args) {
        def server = Server.builder()
                .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
                      public void handle(final Ev ev){
                          ev.dispatch(this)
                      }
                    }
                }).build()
        server.start()
    }
}
```

One is mismatched curly braces in the anonymous inner class definition.  There are 3 closing curly braces (}) in a row when there should only be 2.

The other appears to be a bug in Groovy.  See https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-7020.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Corrected brace problem in the question. So is probably a groovy bug? Thank you. I'll follow the bug report. In the meantime I have declared the anonimous inner classes as a regular, separate file, classes and all works good. Ho I can write it in more concise way in groovy when the bug was fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy, [`this`, `owner` and `delegate` usually mean the same thing](http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-closures-owner-delegate) within a closure.

Groovy (ironically?) doesn't let you anonymously reference anonymous closures via a keyword. You have to name the closure in the owner's scope, and then you can reference it via that name. If you declare it as a field in the owner then you should be able to self-reference directly, but in this case you're declaring it inside a static method, so that probably won't work. Instead, you can just set `handler.delegate = handler` and then use `delegate` inside the closure to self-reference.

Also, I don't think you're supposed to declare a method within the closure—you just write the code directly. I think this is what you want:

```
class HelloWorld {
    static main(args) {
        def handler = { ev -> 
            ev.dispatch(delegate)
        } as HttpHandler
        handler.delegate = handler
        def server = Server.builder()
                .setHandler(handler).build()
        server.start()
    }
}
```

That kills some of the brevity that using closures is supposed to give you, but apparently that's what you're stuck with.

Comment: Your code give me this exception groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: handler for class: mypkg.Underdog

Comment: @FabianoTaioli - You're right—I overlooked the fact that it was being declared inside a method. The closure semantics for Groovy are really weird. I've altered my answer—hopefully it will work for you now.

Comment: got this -> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: delegate for class: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4